# Downloading images using Picasso creates incorrect images in cache, possible fix?

Tags: java, android, image, picasso

I have a Realm database with image `URL`s, and I need to download these images in the `ExternalCacheDir` . Now here lies the **problem** : assume I have three images : `ar11.jpg`,`ar12.jpg`,`ar13.jpg` . Once my code is executed, I obtain 3 jpg images in the cache dir, with the above mentioned names, however all three images are the replicas of the last image, ie `ar13.jpg` with the names `ar11`,`ar12`,`ar13`.

Here is my code:

```
 private void downloadImage()
{
    RealmResults<ARDatabase> results = mRealm.where(ARDatabase.class).findAll();

    for(ARDatabase x:results)
    {
        if(!x.getIsDownloaded())
        {
            mdataCollection.add(new DownLoadList(x.getUrlImg(),x.getUid()));
        }
    }

    for(DownLoadList i:mdataCollection)
    {
        Log.e("Link",""+i.getImageUrl());
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(i.getImageUrl()).into(target);
    }
}

 private Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
    {
        Log.e("PICASSO","SUCCESSFUL");


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                File sd = getExternalCacheDir();
                File folder = new File(sd, "/arproject/");
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    if (!folder.mkdir()) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "Cannot create a directory!");
                    } else {
                        folder.mkdirs();
                    }
                }

                //File[] fileName = {new File(folder, "one.jpg"), new File(folder, "two.jpg")};


                for (DownLoadList i:mdataCollection)
                {
                    File fileName = new File(folder,i.getUid().toLowerCase()+".jpg");


                    if (!fileName.exists()) {
                        try {
                            fileName.createNewFile();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        try {
                            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(fileName));
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                            outputStream.close();

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                }


            }
        }).start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable)
    {
        Log.e("PICASSO","FAILED"+errorDrawable.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
};
```

What is probably causing this redundancy, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target is called for each image.

Each image is getting written in cache under every name.

First `ar11.jpg` is saved as `ar11.jpg, ar12.jpg, ar13.jpg`.
Then same happens with `ar12.jpg` and `ar13.jpg`

Try this code:

```
private void downloadImage()
{
    RealmResults<ARDatabase> results = mRealm.where(ARDatabase.class).findAll();

    for(ARDatabase x:results)
    {
        if(!x.getIsDownloaded())
        {
            mdataCollection.add(new DownLoadList(x.getUrlImg(),x.getUid()));
        }
    }

    for(DownLoadList i:mdataCollection)
    {
        Log.e("Link",""+i.getImageUrl());
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(i.getImageUrl()).into(getTarget(i));
    }
}

private Target getTarget(DownLoadList downLoadList) {
    Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
        {
            Log.e("PICASSO","SUCCESSFUL");

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    File sd = getExternalCacheDir();
                    File folder = new File(sd, "/arproject/");
                    if (!folder.exists()) {
                        if (!folder.mkdir()) {
                            Log.e("ERROR", "Cannot create a directory!");
                        } else {
                            folder.mkdirs();
                        }
                    }

                    //File[] fileName = {new File(folder, "one.jpg"), new File(folder, "two.jpg")};


                    File fileName = new File(folder, downLoadList.getUid().toLowerCase()+".jpg");


                    if (!fileName.exists()) {
                        try {
                            fileName.createNewFile();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        try {
                            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(fileName));
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                            outputStream.close();

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }).start();

        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable)
        {
            Log.e("PICASSO","FAILED"+errorDrawable.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }

    }
    return target;
}
```